# Hiding the boot-up text in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I installed **`Startup Manager`** in Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty) to try to hide the boot text that is displayed on screen. I've played with numerous combinations of options as described in [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StartUpManager). Particularly these:

> - Show bootloader menu. When selected the bootloader menu displays available
>     options such as kernels, recovery
>     modes, memtest86+, and other operating
>     systems, if installed. If this option
>     is not selected, no bootloader menu
>     will be displayed during boot. The
>     default or saved OS selection will be
>     used.
> - Show boot splash. Enables the splash screen viewed during the boot process.
> - Show text during boot.
> - Manage bootloader themes. Add or remove an installed bootloader theme.
> - Usplash theme.

[image]

**However, nothing makes the boot messages go away**, starting with "Reading files need for boot" and then listing a whole bunch of information such as setting up the firewall etc, which drivers are loaded etc.

Is there any other approach I could use?

Comment: Have yo uchecked `dmesg` output to see if the system tried unsuccessfuly to initialize the graphical boot?

Comment: nagul: no. i assumed that if graphical boot failed, then gnome would fail too. but your're right - they're not neces sarily related - i will try to figure out how to set this option. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable boot messages, you need to pass the `quiet` option to the kernel at boot time. This is usually done by editing the grub configuration file at `/boot/grub/menu.lst`.

Detailed descriptions on exactly how to go about this on Ubuntu can be found in the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Change%20Boot%20Options%20Permanently%20On%20An%20Existing%20Installation).

Note that you are NOT supposed to uncomment the `# kopt=<options go here>` line, as all the commented lines in the `menu.lst` file is parsed by `update-grub`, which modifies the kernel entries further down in the file accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To also hide kernel messages (when booting in text mode (e.g. with `nomodeset`)), I found out that one has to pass `loglevel=3` to the kernel.

This is very useful when systemd stops at a crypto prompt "Please enter passphrase for disk", and it used to be spammed with kernel messages about audio devices and other stuff.

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively, you could run Karmic, it has one built in and it's pretty much a Release Candidate now.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1238409&page=10

Comment: Alpha 6 != Release Candidate. Doubly true for the 64-bit builds. I'm using the karmic alpha right now, and it's nice, but I wouldn't recommend it as a solution to any specific problem.